# Expectation: Is this statment true or is there a counter example

Tags: random-variables, examples-counterexamples, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(X_i)_{i\in (1,...,N)}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables with $0<\mathbb{E}(X_i^2)<0$. Is

$$\sup_i|X_i|<\infty$$

a consequence of the strong law of large numbers, or is there a counterexample?

Comment: I don't understand what the displayed inequality means. There are finitely many variables; thus their supremum is their maximum and is necessarily finite.

Comment: $0<\mathbb{E}(X_i^2)<0$ looks meaningless to me.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant $0 < \operatorname E(X_i^2) <+\infty. \qquad$

Comment: Where you wrote $0<\operatorname E(X_i^2)<0,$ I will guess that you meant $0<\operatorname E(X_i^2)<+\infty.$ You wrote $(X_i)_{i\in(1,\ldots,N)},$ which, taken literally, means you have only finitely many random variables. Also, not that one should write $i\in\{1,\ldots,N\},$ with $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ indicating a set rather than a tuple. Since the strong law of large numbers applies only to an infinite sequence, not to a finite sequence, I will guess that you actually intended an infinite sequence. You could have written $(X_i)_{i\,\in\,\mathbb N}$ or $(X_i)_{i\,=\,1,2,3,\ldots}.\quad$

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are asking about an *infinite* sequence $X_1,X_2,\dots$ of iid random variables, and you want to know whether $\sup_i |X_i|<\infty$ holds almost surely.

If $X_1$ is bounded, meaning $P(|X_1|\le M)=1$ , then trivially we will have $P(\sup |X_i|\le M)=1$.

If $X_1$ is unbounded, however, then the answer is no. For any $M>0$, then the event $\{|X_i|>M\}$ will have a nonzero probability, so with probability one it will occur for some $i$. Therefore, with probability one, $\sup_i |X_i|\ge M$ for all positive integers $M$, so $\sup_i |X_i| = \infty$ with probability $1$.